# Delayed load of elements in TabLayout Android Studio error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

### Problem

When I run on the phone, I press lib item(*Bottom Menu Library Item*). It shows correctly. Then, when I change the fragment (ex: Home Fragment(*Bottom Menu Home Item*) and reselect lib item(*Bottom Menu Library Item*) recycler view inside it disappears. To solve I need to wait or relaunch the app. Below my code in Java.

#### My Fragment Page Adapter

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> lstFragment = new ArrayList<>(); // this line can cause crashes
    private final List<String> lstTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return lstFragment.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lstFragment.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return lstTitles.get(position);
    }

    public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String Title){
        lstFragment.add(fragment); // this line can cause crashes
        lstTitles.add(Title);
    }

}
```

#### RecyclerView Adapter code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context mContext;
    List<Focus> mData;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Focus> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_item_home, viewGroup, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(mData.get(i).getTitle());
        myViewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(mData.get(i).getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imgView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_title);
            imgView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_image);
        }
    }

}
```

#### Main Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button music_ImageView;
    private TextView music_title, music_state, music_duration, music_currentTime;
    private SeekBar music_playerSeekbar;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_menu);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        /**-------------------------------------------------------------------------**/
        music_ImageView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.music_player_btn);
        music_currentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        music_duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTotalDuration);
        music_playerSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.music_player_seekbar);
        music_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.music_player_title);
        music_state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.music_player_state);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        music_playerSeekbar.setMax(100);

        music_ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(Updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    music_ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    music_state.setText("Pause");

                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    music_ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    music_state.setText("Playing");
                    updateSeekBar();
                }
            }
        });

        prepareMediaPlayer();

        music_playerSeekbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) v;

                int playPosition = (mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 100) * seekBar.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
                music_currentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                return true;
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                music_playerSeekbar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                music_playerSeekbar.setProgress(0);
                music_ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                music_currentTime.setText(R.string.zero);
                music_duration.setText(R.string.zero);
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                prepareMediaPlayer();
            }
        });

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment())
                .commit();
        }

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setElevation(0);
        actionBar.setTitle("Brain.Music");
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    RelativeLayout muz = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.music_player);

                    ActionBar actionBar;

                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.menu_home: {
                            bottomNav.getMenu().getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                            actionBar.setTitle("Brain.Music");
                            muz.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_fav: {
                            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                            selectedFragment = new FavFragment();
                            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                            actionBar.setTitle("Favorite");
                            muz.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_lib: {
                            bottomNav.getMenu().getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
                            selectedFragment = new LibFragment();
                            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                            actionBar.setTitle("Library");
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment)
                            .commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };
    private void prepareMediaPlayer(){
        try{
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            music_duration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        }catch (Exception exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private Runnable Updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekBar();
            long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            music_currentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        }
    };

    private void updateSeekBar(){
        if ( mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            music_playerSeekbar.setProgress((int)((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration() * 100));
            handler.postDelayed(Updater, 1000);
        }
    }

    private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliSeconds){
        String timerString = "";
        String secondsString = "";

        int hours = (int)(milliSeconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int)(milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
        int seconds = (int)(milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60) % ((1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        if ( hours > 0 ){
            timerString = hours + ":";
        }
        if ( seconds < 10 ){
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        }else{
            secondsString = "" + seconds;
        }
        timerString = timerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
        return timerString;
    }
}
```

#### Lib Fragment

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class LibFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    private BottomNavigationView btnNav;
    private Fragment fragment;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lib, container, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        /// Adding fragments

        /// Adapter Setting
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentFocus(), "Focus"); // `FragmentFocus()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentSleep(), "Sleep"); // `FragmentSleep()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentRelax(), "Relax"); // `FragmentRelax()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    }

}
```

#### Fragment Focus Code

```
package com.xcube.demo_nav;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FragmentFocus extends Fragment {

    View v;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Category>  lstCategory;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.focus_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_library);
        CategoryRecyclerView recyclerViewAdapter = new CategoryRecyclerView(getContext(), lstCategory);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lstCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        lstCategory.add(new Category("Lo-FI", R.drawable.icon_focus));
        lstCategory.add(new Category("Lo-FI", R.drawable.icon_focus));
        lstCategory.add(new Category("Forest", R.drawable.icon_relax));
    }

}
```